# Redirection in jsp

Tags: jsp

logout.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%
session.invalidate();
response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
response.setHeader("Location","login.jsp"); 
%>
```

checklogin.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%
if (session.getAttribute("UserName") != null && session.getAttribute("IPAddr") != null) {

    } else{
        response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
        response.setHeader("Location","login.jsp"); 
    }
%>
```

HTML
index.php

```
<body>
    <jsp:include page="checklogin.jsp" />
    <div class="Maindiv">
        <div id="Header">
          <jsp:include page="Header.jsp" /> 
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Header.jsp

```
<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                            <span class="lblDarkGray10">Welcome, <strong><%=(String)session.getAttribute("UserName") %></strong></span>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" valign="top" style="padding-left:5px; border-left:solid 1px lightgray;">
                            <a href="logout.jsp" class="lnkDarkGray10">Logout</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                    
                    <td colspan="2" align="right" valign="top">
                         <span class="lblDarkGray10"><%=(String)session.getAttribute("IPAddr")%></span>
                        </td>                       
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Redirection of page
logout.jsp-working
checklogin.jsp-not working

if user direct visit index.jsp then it should be redirect to login.jsp

Comment: Why are you trying to `include` , just redirect from the index ...

Comment: `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<c:redirect url="checklogin.jsp" />`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of Servlet filters to do login check. This way you can avoid writing the login check code in every file you don't want the user to access without login.

Here is good [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) for servlet filters.

Servlet filters are not only used for login check, but for several issues like authentication, visitor counts, transforming requests etc.